# Unable to access uicollectionview cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to access a cell in the collection view and then change the font weight to bold when the user taps on the cell but i seem to be having some issues. When trying to access outlets in my collection view i'm getting this error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

But i don't seem to understand this because the identifiers for the cell is correct and also the class name is correct as well.

**The protocol for dealing with the cell selection**

```
protocol InfiniteCollectionViewDelegate
{
    func didSelectCellAtIndexPath(collectionView: UICollectionView, unmodifiedIndexPath: NSIndexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
}
```

**Using the protocol**

```
extension InfiniteCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        infiniteDelegate?.didSelectCellAtIndexPath(self, unmodifiedIndexPath: indexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: getCorrectedIndex(indexPath.row - indexOffset), inSection: 0))
    }
}
```

**The way i'm setting up the collection view**

```
func cellForItemAtIndexPath(collectionView: UICollectionView, dequeueIndexPath: NSIndexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath)  -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = navigationCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newsCell", forIndexPath: dequeueIndexPath) as! newsTypeCell
    cell.newsTypeLbl.text = cellItems[usableIndexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

**The action for accessing the collection view cell outlet**

```
func didSelectCellAtIndexPath(collectionView: UICollectionView, unmodifiedIndexPath: NSIndexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    navigationCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(unmodifiedIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)

    let cell = navigationCollectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(usableIndexPath) as! newsTypeCell

    print(cell.newsTypeLbl.text)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the crash from happening by safely unwrapping cell. newsTypeLbl with an if let statement.

```
if let label = cell.newsTypeLbl{
    label.text = cellItems[usableIndexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to print the value in the label and have tried what you suggested by doing this  `if let label = cell.newsTypeLbl { print(label.text) }` but all that happens is it seems to break at this line `let cell = navigationCollectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(usableIndexPath) as! newsTypeCell`

Comment: The same fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Something that will help you here is to actually use the collection view being passed to you in that delegate method:

```
func didSelectCellAtIndexPath(collectionView: UICollectionView, unmodifiedIndexPath: NSIndexPath, usableIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(unmodifiedIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
...
}
```